# amadeus api faultstring Content-Length is missing stackoverflow

Tags: php, api, curl, content-length, amadeus

I'm trying to get my fist Amadeus API call to work.

•• I'm able to retrieve a token ••

```
$url = 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/security/oauth2/token';
$curls = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=--key--&client_secret=--secret--');
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$token = curl_exec($curls);
curl_close($curls);
```

**but after I get the token, I can't go further....**

When I try this code

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 0,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=>469,
CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-dates?origin=NYC&destination=LON&oneWay=false&nonStop=false",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: Bearer --token--")
));

$response = curl_exec($curl); $err = curl_error($curl); curl_close($curl);

echo $response;
```

I get

```
{"fault":{"faultstring":"Content-Length is missing","detail":{"errorcode":"messaging.adaptors.http.flow.LengthRequired"}}}
```

What I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find a working example below:

```
$url = 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-dates?origin=NYC&destination=MOW&oneWay=false&nonStop=false';
$curls = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($curls, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer access_token'));
$result = curl_exec($curls);
    if (curl_errno($curls)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($curls);
    }
print_r ($result);
curl_close ($curls);
```

Note:

- I changed the destination as NYC to LON is not part of the dataset we have in the test environment (you can find the list [here](https://github.com/amadeus4dev/data-collection/blob/master/data/flightsearch.md)).
- the URL you used was `api.amadeus.com` which is the production environment but you get a token from `test.api.amadeus.com` which is the test environment. In the example, I call the test environment.

Comment: thanks, I now realize the https://test.api. vs https://api.   ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do a shell_exec and it works.
The same url (test.api.amadeus.com.....) in php cURL was not working.

working code for me :

```
$shopping_flight_destinations_par = 'https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-destinations?origin=PAR&maxPrice=200';
$amadex_cmd = "/usr/bin/curl -X GET '".$shopping_flight_destinations_par."' -H 'Authorization: Bearer ".$amadeus_token."'";
$amadex_jsond = json_decode(shell_exec($amadex_cmd),true);
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($amadex_jsond); echo '</pre>';
```